# WCF Service architecture for multiple services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, design-patterns

I'm after a bit of advice here, so I go in the right direction.

I had one service, which did all my business functions in one service, such as:

```
TestingService
      GetProducts()
      GetPeople()
```

Now, I feel, as my system is growing, I want to split these out, so:

```
ProductService
    GetProducts()
PeopleService
    GetPeople()
```

Is the best approach for this to have two .svc files in the same project and call them each individually? I've implemented a repository pattern which is working nicely, and now have IProductService and IPeopleService. If I was to do this, and I used both constructors in my Controller - I'd get something like this:

```
public TestController(IProductService productService, IPeopleService service)
```

rather than

```
public TestController(ITestService service)
```

which I had originally.

Which could become unwieldy if I'm using 5 services in a single Controller? Is this what Factory classes are used for, as a Service-level wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll want to have your services in repository classes not the controllers.  Something like this:

```
public TestRepository(IProductService productService)  {}
```

If you opt for the more granular approach that you mention, you'll have many services instead of one large one - good idea.  Also, if you have a 1 to 1 to 1 relationship among your controller/repository/service, then you'll have nice and maintainable structure.

However, if your relationship is 1 to many, then a factory approach is certainly an option.  Maybe something along these lines:

```
// Factory
     public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
        {
         public IProductService GetProductService()
            {
                return new ProductService();
            }
         public IPeopleService GetPeopleService ()
            {
                return new PeopleService ();
            }
          }

// Repository
    public class ProductRepository
        {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // use dependecy injection to avoid this tight coupling
            var factory = new ServiceFactory(); 
            var service = factory.GetProductService();
            service.DoMyStuff();
        }

}
```